# Nasty Virus, can't find or remove, prevents from clicking or interacting with forms, even task manager

Tags: windows-7, mouse, virus, anti-virus

two days ago I opened a GIF file that apparently wasn't really a GIF file. Now, my left mouse click button is the middle mouse button, forms are unclickable or typable (they are "frozen" but not hanging/crashed, like they are suspended by the virus or something).

I ran all sorts of antivirus programs, rootkit scans, and more. I was forced to use bootable antivirus software because I can no longer click anything in Windows (even in safe mode, even at login screen).

I saw a weird startup exe through CCleaner like q123awesd.exe or something in my appdata folder, deleted it, yet nothing.

I'm at a loss here, I can't find it and my computer is unusable. I have my OS on an SSD and everything else on another HDD, but cannot determine which drive it is on. Anyone have this?

EDIT: I even tried messing with mouse/keyboard drivers, using different mice, clearing everything with CCleaner including all startup processes. Could it be a windows service? I'm super frustrated.

Comment: back up what matters and nuke it from orbit. Its the only way to be sure.

Comment: Hate to say it... @JourneymanGeek's unpleasant-sounding advice really is right on.  One of the creators of the C language made a very famous presentation "Reflections of Trust" where he described that a compromised computer can lie.  So if you run anti-virus software, the compromised computer can tell the anti-virus software that it cleaned the computer, when it didn't.  There's no way for the anti-virus software to overpower sufficiently advanced malware, so the safest solution is to start with something trusted like an operating system install disc.  Otherwise, you're gambling.

Comment: Be sure to not include the virus in your backup. That means, anything that can be executed might contain the virus (programs etc). Luckily you usually need to install them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the computer in Save Mode (with networking). In this case, Windows will start with minimal amount of programs run. This could give you some relief until you find a way to remove the malware.

P.S. Tell us which anti-virus programs you have tried?

Comment: The virus is there in safe mode. I've tried malwarebytes, windows defender, anvira (bootable) and some other weird bootable one.

Comment: you could contact antivirus companies with request for help. I suppose these will be free service for you, because it will enhance their products. And something other - if you can, try with non-bootable solutions, because they are with older virus signatures. I am happy with AVG Free